# Smooth transitions and animation (for mobile and desktop - cross browser and should support IE 7 or later)

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate

I am making a website with a lots of animations and transitions. But the problem is that all my animations work well with IE10 or later and also with chrome. However in Mozilla, it's not that smooth. So I tried using [**this plugin**](http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/), which did the work pretty well, but it didn't work in IE7 and 8.

So after searching over stackoverflow, I used [**GSAP**](http://www.greensock.com/gsap-js/), which was working okay but still not that smooth in Mozilla. I have a responsive design, which has a slide menu for mobile devices, which slides in from the left side. Even that's terribly animating.

Please help me with this. I know there are millions of same post in here. But I just can't get want I exactly want.

Comment: I think you need to look at using jquery transit as your optimal choice and then degrade gracefully from there. I had the same issue and in the end I gave up. Mozilla does not work too well with jquery transit at all. In fact there are lots of issues on the github plugin page about it. I would try some bog standard straight css animations for non compliant browsers.

Comment: But it doesn't support IE9 as well, I really want my site to work in IE9 or IE8 atleast.